# HTTP method DELETE doesn't support output

Tags: apex, integration, httprequest

I've done many integrations so far but none of them required sending an HTTP request with the 'DELETE' method. And today, surprise - `HTTP method DELETE doesn't support output` appears in my log when I try to make this call.

I couldn't find any related questions/answers on this error apart from [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F00000008r52IAA).

The code is simple:

```
Http h = new Http ();

httpRequest = new HttpRequest ();
httpRequest.setEndpoint('https://somedomain.com/api/deleteRecord/recordId');
httpRequest.setMethod('DELETE');
httpRequest.setBody('');

h.send(httpRequest);
```

The [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_restful_http_httprequest.htm#apex_System_HttpRequest_setMethod) says that the DELETE method is supported too, though there isn't any additional information on this.

Is there a different way of implementing this method or is there something obvious that I'm missing here?

Comment: any good answer for this? I also have this problem when delete a record to other server.

Comment: @robertpeter07 As you can see from the answers, you are not allowed to set the body in a delete request.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd suggest you need to avoid the call to setBody() when making a DELETE call

I doubt DELETE permits an http body of any size.

Answer (score 2):

Since I had the code in a static method, I was setting the body to whatever comes in the parameter.

If you ever get this problem, avoid setting the body:

```
if (String.isNotBlank(body))
{
    httpRequest.setBody(body);
}
```

Worked like a charm!

Comment: This doesn't seem clear to me.